# con select erroneo

Tags: mysql, oracle, sql, select

Tengo dos tablas, una de *USUARIO* y otra de *DOCUMENTOS*.

Estas dos tablas están relacionadas por *ID_USUARIO*, un usuario puede tener varios documentos.

Ej:

Un USUARIO tiene 5 registros en *DOCUMENTOS*, uno con `id 1` otro con `3, 5, 7, y 8`.

Necesito recuperar todos los *USUARIOS* a los que les falten los *documentos* con `ID 2,4,6 y 9`.

En un rango de fechas especifico.

Utilizo Oracle sql.

Ej: QUERY USADA

```
SELECT NUM_USUARIO, FECHA_CREACION FROM USUARIO_TB
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT U.ID FROM USUARIO_TB U
JOIN DOCUMENTOS_TB DOC ON DOC.EXPEDIENT_ID = U.ID
WHERE DOC.DOCUMENTO_ID IN (2,4,6,9)
AND U.FECHA_CREACION BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') 
AND TO_DATE('31/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY'))
AND FECHA_CREACION BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') 
AND TO_DATE('31/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY')
ORDER BY id DESC
```

El problema es que me printa USUARIOS que SI tienen uno de los documentos que pido en la query QUE FALTEN.

Comment: muestra el diseño de de las tablas y su relación para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Utiliza el **NOT IN** WHERE DOC.DOCUMENTO_ID NOT IN (2,4,6,9)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo más simple haciendo un **select**, relacionando las tablas con un **inner join** e indicando que muestre aquellos que no tengan los documentos id que indicas con **not in**.

```
SELECT NUM_USUARIO, FECHA_CREACION 
 FROM USUARIO_TB U
INNER JOIN DOCUMENTOS_TB DOC 
 ON DOC.EXPEDIENT_ID = U.ID
WHERE DOC.DOCUMENTO_ID NOT IN (2,4,6,9)
AND U.FECHA_CREACION BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') 
AND TO_DATE('31/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY'))
AND FECHA_CREACION BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') 
AND TO_DATE('31/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY')
ORDER BY id DESC
```

De esta manera te traería todos los USUARIOS a los que les falten los documentos con ID 2,4,6 y 9.

La subconsulta es innecesaria y antiperformante, en bases con muchos registros notarías la diferencia.

Saludos.